# Copy constructor vs move constructor in lambda capture list

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, capture

I am confused by behavior of clang on OSX vs. GCC on Ubuntu.

Context: I am trying to build a library on OSX. The library is not known to be buildable on OSX, and this question is not about the reasons; rather I am questioning my understanding of c++ move constructor semantics in lambda capture lists.

A lambda expression has a capture, which uses std::move. According to my understanding of C++, a move constructor should be chosen to initialize the implicit auto variable that the capture creates.

This is what's happening when I compile the code on Ubuntu 14.4

When I compile the same code on OSX, I get the following error [see *snippet 1* below], which suggests that instead of the move constructor, a copy constructor is selected. The code, however, deletes the copy constructor to make instances moveable, but not copyable [see *snippet 2* below]

GCC version on Ubnutu

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-174:~$ c++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v 
  --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3' 
  --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs 
  --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ 
  --prefix=/usr 
  --program-suffix=-4.8 
  --enable-shared 
  --enable-linker-build-id 
  --libexecdir=/usr/lib 
  --without-included-gettext 
  --enable-threads=posix 
  --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 
  --libdir=/usr/lib 
  --enable-nls 
  --with-sysroot=/ 
  --enable-clocale=gnu 
  --enable-libstdcxx-debug 
  --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes 
  --enable-gnu-unique-object 
  --disable-libmudflap 
  --enable-plugin 
  --with-system-zlib 
  --disable-browser-plugin 
  --enable-java-awt=gtk 
  --enable-gtk-cairo 
  --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre 
  --enable-java-home 
  --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 
  --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 
  --with-arch-directory=amd64 
  --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar 
  --enable-objc-gc 
  --enable-multiarch 
  --disable-werror 
  --with-arch-32=i686 
  --with-abi=m64 
  --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 
  --with-tune=generic 
  --enable-checking=release 
  --build=x86_64-linux-gnu 
  --host=x86_64-linux-gnu 
  --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
 Thread model: posix
 gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
```

Clang version on OSX

```
shapira-MBA:wangle omer$ c++ -v
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

The code is compiled with the following flags:

```
-I/Users/omer/git/wangle/wangle/..  
-I/usr/local/include 
-I/opt/local/include 
-I/Users/omer/git/wangle/wangle/gtest/src/gtest/googlemock/include 
-I/Users/omer/git/wangle/wangle/gtest/src/gtest/googletest/include  
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk   
-std=c++1y 
-fPIC
```

Snippet 1 (with extra newlines to make compiler output more readable, and with irrelevant second capture removed):

```
/Users/omer/git/wangle/wangle/../wangle/concurrent/FutureExecutor.h:63:11: note: 
   copy constructor of '' is implicitly deleted 
   because field '' has a deleted copy constructor
    [ promise = std::move(promise)]() mutable {
      ^
/usr/local/include/folly/futures/Promise.h:35:3: note: 'Promise' has been
   explicitly marked deleted here
   Promise(Promise const&) = delete;
   ^
```

Snippet 2 (constructors of the Promise class):

```
// not copyable
Promise(Promise const&) = delete;
Promise& operator=(Promise const&) = delete;

// movable
Promise(Promise<T>&&) noexcept;
Promise& operator=(Promise<T>&&) noexcept;
```

My question is: according to which rule the copy constructor is being invoked? Is this a case of UB?

Comment: Something in your code is trying to copy the *lambda* somehow. It's not the capture that is the problem. Also, init-capture is C++14.

Comment: without the surrounding code it is difficult to tell. The move does nothing but a cast to an r-value, which should result in the r-value version of the assignment operator being chosen. I would suspect you make an implicit copy somewhere, but without any surrounding code this is impossible to tell.

Comment: Seems that @T.C. is right, the *lambda* is getting copied. The copy constructor for the lambda is implicitly disabled.
The full error is here http://pastebin.com/3zK7rgsD